# With Firebase , using react hooks , objects are not valid as a React child , (If you meant) to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a web app that just post some data which includes latitude and longitude of the user but the problem is if the user denied the request (access location) latitude and longitude won't be posted in Firebase (database) I just want to print message of

const [message, setMessage] = useState(null)

the message includes error code if  permission is denied, but I m unable to show it by the ternary operator the error I received is Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {message}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
please help me out

[app interface (mobile view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JenY8.jpg)

[full code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/practise-loco-28049?file=/src/All.js)

[Updated]

I know my approach is little bit off track , but what should I do

If u want
if user denies request , input box and button replace with error code?????

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const All = () => {
  const [locationOption, setLocationOption] = useState({
    lat: null,
    long: null,
    speed: null,
    position: null
  });
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [showErrorMessage, setShowErrorMessage] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    

    // Get current location and position + shows erroe of denying request
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        setLocationOption({
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          long: position.coords.longitude,
          speed: position.coords.speed,
          positon: position
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        setMessage({
          message:
            "Error : " +
            error.code +
            "." +
            error.message +
            ". \n You should all the location request :-( "
        });
      }
    );
    //ends
  }, []);

  const showErrorMessageFunction = () => {
    setShowErrorMessage({ showErrorMessage:message })
  }

  
  //ends
  

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(message);
  }, [message]);



  useEffect(()=>{
    showErrorMessageFunction();
  })

  

 

  return (
    <div>

      <br />
      <br />
      <>
        {showErrorMessage ? (
          // {message.map(e => <div>{e.message}</div>)}
           message
        ) : (
          <>
            wait till some number appears below
            <br />
            <br />
            {locationOption.lat}/{locationOption.long}
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="text" />
                <button>
                   click
                </button>
            <br />
            <br />
          </>
        )}
      </>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};
export default All;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off. You are using class based components syntax instead of functional components:
When you are using setSomething, you don't need to mention which attribute is about to change. Instead of setMessage({ message: 'something'}) you need to write setMessage('something').

You also start with showErrorMessage as true - which means you are trying to render null when page renders.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const All = () => {
  const [locationOption, setLocationOption] = useState({
    lat: null,
    long: null,
    speed: null,
    position: null
  });
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [showErrorMessage, setShowErrorMessage] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    

    // Get current location and position + shows erroe of denying request
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        setLocationOption({
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          long: position.coords.longitude,
          speed: position.coords.speed,
          positon: position
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        setMessage(
            "Error : " +
            error.code +
            "." +
            error.message +
            ". \n You should all the location request :-( "
       );
      }
    );
    //ends
  }, []);

  const showErrorMessageFunction = () => {
    setShowErrorMessage(message)
  }

  
  //ends
  

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(message);
  }, [message]);



  useEffect(()=>{
    showErrorMessageFunction();
  })

  

 

  return (
    <div>

      <br />
      <br />
      <>
        {showErrorMessage ? (
          // {message.map(e => <div>{e.message}</div>)}
           message
        ) : (
          <>
            wait till some number appears below
            <br />
            <br />
            {locationOption.lat}/{locationOption.long}
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="text" />
                <button>
                   click
                </button>
            <br />
            <br />
          </>
        )}
      </>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};
export default All;
```

Comment: Firstly I did this method only , and I was trying all the possibility

Comment: The error means that "message" is not a string, it's an Object.
Can you test if this is the issue by changing your code to --> setMessage('error message - test')

Comment: Now I see the issue - you are trying to render message when page loads, because showErrorMessage is true and message is null, you cannot render null as it is an object.

Comment: If we will code as you answer above , app goes to rerendering , and never stops and nothing display IDE STOPED RESPONDING ,,,

Comment: Yes message is an object

Comment: Now what should I do , if I declare showErrorMessage as nor true neither false , that is null

Comment: I just want , if user denies request , input box and button replace with error code?????